# Can two linux pc's can be use as one signle screen

Tags: linux

Can two linux pc can be use as one signle screen (half in first pc and second half in another pc).Basically can 2 pc's used to see a single movie at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen is controlled by your operating system. So there is no standard way to let on screen be shared by to different OS.

But if you manage a remote connection on your main OS to your seconds OS, for instance  by ssh, you can use them with one screen.

Visual tools like TeamViewer, VNC or the Remote Desktop protocol would also enable you to bring the output of a second system to your single monitor.

Comment: This will definitely lead to some kind of lag or video losses.  I am suggesting to try to read and sync the same file on both computers, or of course to plug a screen back into the first, why not?

Comment: so can I able to see half screen in one and other half in other pc( with same type of os ) , is there any cooked solution presents??

Comment: What about a KVM switch?

Comment: @OkieOth dont have KVM switch, Can it be solved by software solution?